# On Jekyll (Liquid) can't get where working

Tags: where-clause, jekyll, liquid, assign

I have a people.yml like

```
- name: Foo
  activities:
    - title: bar1
    - title: bar2
```

And an assign like

```
{% assign person = site.data.people | where: "activities.title", "bar1" %}
```

When I previously had only one activity per person (without having the title attribute) I could easily make it work. But now I'm struggling with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass an `Array` to the `where` filter. It will not try to find the desired value by looping over all Hashes like `{"title"=>"bar1"}`, it will simply evaluate the property against the passed string. So, those `Hash` will never be equal to `bar1`.

My two cents :

Simplify **people.yml** by removing `activities.name` key :
Note : the two `activities` array presentations are equivalent.

```
- name: Foo
  activities: [ bar1, bar2 ]

- name: Bar
  activities:
    - bar3
    - bar4
```

You can now use the `contains` filter to retrieve people that have bar1 as an activity. `contains` filters `strings` or `array` like `["bar1", "bar2"]`

```
{% assign selected = "" | split: "/" %} --> create empty array
{% for people in site.data.people %}
    {% if people.activities contains 'bar1' %}
        --> add people to array if match is found
        {% assign selected = selected | push: people %} 
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```